# using prebuilt static/shared libs for my executable: Android makefile

Tags: linker, static-libraries, object-files, android.mk

seems this questions is asked couple of times and i have visited all of them and it did not help thus posting here..
**objective:** making executable using prebuilt libraries(static and shared) staying parallel to my exe code

DIR1--------- lib1/lib2/...libx/myExeDir

```
 a. lib1/lib2/..libx may be interdependent.
 b. if i remove myExeDir from Android.mk of DIR1, all static and shared libs are compiled fine (lib1..libx)
 c. if i add myExeDir:android.mk in DIR1 android.mk file , i see so many linking issues of multiple definitions, while in myExeDir code i am just using the functionalities provided..Issue i see is same object files is being included multiple times through different static .a files. I guess i am missing some linking option in the android.mk file of myExeDir but not getting any luck.(tried --no-whole-archive but seems not helping).
```

.Here is the android.mk file of myExeDir

```
ifeq ($(CAM_PATH),)
LOCAL_PATH := $(abspath $(call my-dir)/../..)
CAM_PATH := $(abspath $(LOCAL_PATH)/../..)
else
LOCAL_PATH := $(CAM_PATH)/src/jpeg_app
endif

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES += $(TARGET_OUT_INTERMEDIATES)/KERNEL_OBJ/usr

# Module supports function call tracing via ENABLE_FUNCTION_CALL_TRACE
# Required before including common.mk
SUPPORT_FUNCTION_CALL_TRACE := 1

# Get definitions common to the CAM project here
include $(CAM_PATH)/build/infrastructure/android/common.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=                      \
    jpeg_encode.cpp                     \
    jpeg_encode_main.cpp


LOCAL_INC_FILES :=                      \
    jpeg_encode.h                       \


# Put here any libraries that should be linked by CAM projects
LOCAL_C_LIBS := $(CAM_C_LIBS)


# Paths to included headers
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=                                                 \
    hardware/libhardware/include                                    \
    system/media/camera/include/system/                             \
    $(TARGET_OUT_HEADERS)/                                          \
    $(CAM_C_INCLUDES)                                              \

# Compiler flags
LOCAL_CFLAGS := $(CAM_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fexceptions               \
                -g                         \
                -Wno-unused-variable

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := $(CAM_CPPFLAGS)

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := include $(CAM_BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := include $(CAM_BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libCAMcore libCAMutils libCAMosutils libCAMncs

# Libraries to statically link
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES :=  libCAMcsl libCAMsensor libCAMgenerated libCAMhwljpeg libCAMchi libCAMhwltitan17x libCAMhalutils libCAMhal libCAMswljpeg libCAMncs libCAMstats libCAMhwlife libCAMhwlipe libCAMhwliqmodule libCAMswlfdmanager libCAMhwlfd libCAMofflinestats libCAMhwlbps libCAMhwllrme libCAMswlransac libifestriping libCAMiqsetting libCAMdspstreamer libstriping

ifeq ($(IQSETTING),OEM1)
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += \
    libCAMoem1chromatix        \
    liboem1iqsetting
else
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += \
    libCAMiqinterpolation
endif # ($(IQSETTING),OEM1)

# Libraries to link
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES +=               \
    libqdMetaData                       \
    libcamera_metadata                  \
    libCAMfdengine                     \
    libCAMstatscore                    \
    libadsprpc                          \


#LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE   := FALSE

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lz -ldl
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,--no-whole-archive

# Binary name
LOCAL_MODULE := CAMjpegapp

#LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

-include $(CAM_CHECK_WHINER)
include $(CAM_BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
'''

here is the cmd line and error from the logs: 

> FAILED:
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/EXECUTABLES/CAMjpegapp_intermediates/LINKED/CAMjpegapp
> /bin/bash -c
> "vendor/qcom/proprietary/llvm-arm-toolchain-ship/4.0/bin/clang++ -pie
> -nostdlib -Bdynamic -Wl,-dynamic-linker,/system/bin/linker64 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -Wl,-rpath-link=out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/EXECUTABLES/CAMjpegapp_intermediates/jpeg_encode.o
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/EXECUTABLES/CAMjpegapp_intermediates/jpeg_encode_main.o
> -Wl,--whole-archive  out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMcsl_intermediates/libCAMcsl.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMsensor_intermediates/libCAMsensor.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMgenerated_intermediates/libCAMgenerated.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMhwljpeg_intermediates/libCAMhwljpeg.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMchi_intermediates/libCAMchi.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMhwltitan17x_intermediates/libCAMhwltitan17x.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMhalutils_intermediates/libCAMhalutils.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMhal_intermediates/libCAMhal.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMswljpeg_intermediates/libCAMswljpeg.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMncs_intermediates/libCAMncs.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMstats_intermediates/libCAMstats.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMhwlife_intermediates/libCAMhwlife.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMhwlipe_intermediates/libCAMhwlipe.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMhwliqmodule_intermediates/libCAMhwliqmodule.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMswlfdmanager_intermediates/libCAMswlfdmanager.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMhwlfd_intermediates/libCAMhwlfd.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMofflinestats_intermediates/libCAMofflinestats.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMhwlbps_intermediates/libCAMhwlbps.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMhwllrme_intermediates/libCAMhwllrme.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMswlransac_intermediates/libCAMswlransac.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libifestriping_intermediates/libifestriping.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMiqsetting_intermediates/libCAMiqsetting.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMdspstreamer_intermediates/libCAMdspstreamer.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libstriping_intermediates/libstriping.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMiqinterpolation_intermediates/libCAMiqinterpolation.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive   out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMcore_intermediates/libCAMcore.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMutils_intermediates/libCAMutils.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMosutils_intermediates/libCAMosutils.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMncs_intermediates/libCAMncs.a
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libcompiler_rt-extras_intermediates/libcompiler_rt-extras.a   out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libatomic_intermediates/libatomic.a
 out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libgcc_intermediates/libgcc.a
 -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--build-id=md5 -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,-maarch64linux -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--fix-cortex-a53-843419 -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--icf=safe -Wl,--no-undefined-version   -target aarch64-linux-android
 -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin
 -ffp-contract=fast -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -fno-fast-math -Wno-logical-not-parentheses -Wl,--no-fatal-warnings -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-tautological-constant-out-of-range-compare -Ofast out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libc++.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libcutils.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/liblog.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libcdsprpc.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libssc.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libprotobuf-cpp-full.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libqdMetaData.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libcamera_metadata.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libCAMfdengine.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libCAMstatscore.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libadsprpc.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/liblog.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libz.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libdl.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libc++.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libc.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libm.so
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/libdl.so -o
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/EXECUTABLES/CAMjpegapp_intermediates/LINKED/CAMjpegapp
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/lib/crtend_android.o"
> prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold:
> error:
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMncs_intermediates/libCAMncs.a(CAMfdconfig.o):
> **multiple definition of**
> 'CAMfdconfig::FaceDetectionCtrlTypeClass::LoadFDFaceSize(ParameterFileSymbolTableEntry*,
> CAMfdconfig::FDFaceSize*, unsigned long)'
> prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold:
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMgenerated_intermediates/libCAMgenerated.a(CAMfdconfig.o):
> previous definition here
> prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold:
> error:
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMncs_intermediates/libCAMncs.a(CAMfdconfig.o):
> **multiple definition of**
> 'CAMfdconfig::FaceDetectionCtrlTypeClass::LoadFDHwConfig(ParameterFileSymbolTableEntry*,
> CAMfdconfig::FDHwConfig*, unsigned long)'
> prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold:
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMgenerated_intermediates/libCAMgenerated.a(CAMfdconfig.o):
> previous definition here
> prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold:
> error:
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMncs_intermediates/libCAMncs.a(CAMfdconfig.o):
> multiple definition of
> 'CAMfdconfig::FaceDetectionCtrlTypeClass::LoadFDSwConfig(ParameterFileSymbolTableEntry*,
> CAMfdconfig::FDSwConfig*, unsigned long)'
> prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold:
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMgenerated_intermediates/libCAMgenerated.a(CAMfdconfig.o):
> previous definition here
> prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold:
> error:
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMncs_intermediates/libCAMncs.a(CAMfdconfig.o):
> multiple definition of
> 'CAMfdconfig::FaceDetectionCtrlTypeClass::LoadFDMedianFilter(ParameterFileSymbolTableEntry*,
> CAMfdconfig::FDMedianFilter*, unsigned long)'
> prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold:
> out/target/product/camTarget/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libCAMgenerated_intermediates/libCAMgenerated.a(CAMfdconfig.o):
> previous definition here
> prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold:
> error:
```

Comment: Please mention the related links in your questions that doesn't work for you (and would be nice to notice why not)

Comment: oh..actually it is right at the end of makefile above..i did not find any other way to paste logs..mybad..

Comment: will really appreciate any help.. @kitsu